# Comparing date with string Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Lets assume that I have a SQL Server database and a table which looks like:

```
Id int NOT NULL,
Date date NOT NULL
```

I have corresponding entity framework model:

```
public class Bundle
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
}
```

User can type a string that can be anything. I need to find all items where Date, or any part of date, contains string entered by user. So, basically, I need to perform query:

```
SELECT Id, Date
FROM Bundles
WHERE Date LIKE '%user_query_here%'
```

My first attempt was

```
query.Where(b => b.Date.ToShortDateString().Contains(filter.Date))
```

This throws a NotSupportedException, so I tried this:

```
query.Where(b => Convert.ToString(b.Date).Contains(filter.Date));
```

Please note, that *filter.Date* is string. Its not a DateTime structure.

This also throws an exception. So my question is how execute query written above?
PS: I can't perform filtering in memory, this table has many thousands of rows.

Comment: Are you sure about your requirement? This looks really dangerous to me to rely on the string representation of a date. What if the culture between client and server is different?

Comment: Yes, I'm totaly sure. And I'm not afraid about issues, that can happen if culture on server and client are different.

Comment: You're aware this is going to be dog-slow, right, as it won't use indices?  If you had a Calendar table you could run the date-search against that (much smaller table, with separated columns in indices too), which could then be joined as part of a regular range query.... but I'm not sure how to deal with that in Entity Framework.

Comment: Yes, I know about indexes. This is not a big deal because I have no index on this column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no simple way to convert a datetime to string with l2e, sadly.

You may use some [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods

```
SqlFunctions.DatePart
```

will return an int representing a part of the Date (year, month, day for example).

and

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert
```

can help you to convert the int in a string (casting it to double first), which you can then concatenate.

Something like

```
.Where(b => (SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("y", b)) 
           + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", b))
           //etc.
             ).Contains(filter.Date)
```

of course this is unreadable, and really not index-friendly.

A (much) easier and cleaner way, if you're working with **sql server**, would be to create and use a **computed column**.

You can create it like that (google  to find how to do this properly if you use Code First and Migrations)

```
alter table add StringDate as convert(varchar, [Date], 112)//or another format, this will be yyyymmdd
```

If you use code first, you'll have to mark the property with attribute

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

Then you will be able to do

```
.Where(b => b.StringDate.Contains(filter.Date))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for solution. I used computed columns solution.