# How to write a function that can be executed in LinqToEntities without loading the object

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a design problem, but don't know how to fix it.  I have a Policy object, with a boolean property like so:

```
public bool IsCancelled
{
    get
    {
        return (CancellationDate != null && Convert.ToDateTime(CancellationDate) < DateTime.Today);
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that if I want to get...

```
context.Policies.where(q => q.IsCancelled)
```

...LinqToEntities can't execute this against the database; I must load every policy object into memory, like this statement below, which kills performance and is completely unnecessary:

```
context.policies.ToList().where(q => q.IsCancelled)
```

A colleague tells me I should be able to use a Func or Expression to do this, but I'm at a loss as to what phrase to even Google for this.  Can someone recommend a link or two that explains how to do this?

Keep in mind, I want this to be available to queries like the one above, and to an instance of a Policy object in memory, without having to code the logic twice (DRY and all that).

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you can change the type to datetime in the database? This is highly inefficient.

Comment: It is a nullable DateTime. My question isn't about the DateTime check specifically; it's about checking any custom property like my IsCancelled property (the contents of which could easily be coded in my LINQ statement directly, but that would violate the DRY principle).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Convert method. I assume CancelationDate is a string.  The real problem here is that SQL doesn't do date comparisons as strings, they need to be in date format.  This can't be translated to SQL, and thus won't work in the database.

You really should be storing dates as the date type, not as strings.  Then it would be trivial.  If you can change this, then do it, then no conversion is necessary.

Your other option is to futz with the EntityFunctions, SqlFunctions, DbFunctions to try to make it work.

See:
[Comparing date with string Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574564/comparing-date-with-string-entity-framework)

Comment: It is a nullable DateTime.  My question isn't about the DateTime check specifically; it's about checking any custom property like my IsCancelled property (the contents of which could easily be coded in my LINQ statement directly, but that would violate the DRY principle).

Comment: @JamesinIndy - It's really very simple... Can your code execute in a SQL statement?  If you can't see how that is possible, then no... it's not going to work.  If it is possible, then there is probably a Linq-enable function somewhere to do it (like the aforementioned Sql and DbFunctions).  You can't simply inject .NET code into a LinqToEntities statement and have it work unless its translatable to SQL.  In EF7 they are going to be providing a way to do this more easily, but it will still require translation to memory, it will just be a bit more efficient than it currently is.